# How to detect if Buetooth is connected?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am using this code to get notified whenever a bluetooth device is connected or disconnected, however, it does not check whether the bluetooth device is connected as an audio device or not

```
// ...
    IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter(
            BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
    IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(
            BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED);
    IntentFilter filter3 = new IntentFilter(
            BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
    this.registerReceiver(BTReceiver, filter1);
    this.registerReceiver(BTReceiver, filter2);
    this.registerReceiver(BTReceiver, filter3);
}

// The BroadcastReceiver that listens for bluetooth broadcasts
private final BroadcastReceiver BTReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            // Do something if connected
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BT Connected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            // Do something if disconnected
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BT Disconnected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        // else if...
    }
};
```

how do i detect A2DP, btA2dp audio devices?

Answer (score 4):

There are three broadcasts you're supposed to register for to keep track of Bluetooth device connections:

```
// ...

IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter(
    BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(
    BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED);
IntentFilter filter3 = new IntentFilter(
    BluetoothA2dp.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED);

// ...

switch (action) {
    case BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED:
        // Bluetooth state changed (turned on/off)
        break;
    case BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED:
        // Bluetooth connection state changed (device got connected/disconnected)
        break;
    case BluetoothA2dp.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED:
        // Bluetooth device gained/lost it's state as the media audio device
        if(intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothA2dp.EXTRA_STATE, -1) == BluetoothA2dp.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "A2DP device connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        break;
}
```

From the documentation of `BluetoothA2dp.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED`:

> This intent will have 3 extras:
>
> `EXTRA_STATE` - The current state of the profile.
>
> `EXTRA_PREVIOUS_STATE`- The previous state of the profile.
>
> `EXTRA_DEVICE` - The remote device.
>
> `EXTRA_STATE` or `EXTRA_PREVIOUS_STATE` can be any of `STATE_DISCONNECTED`,
>   `STATE_CONNECTING`, `STATE_CONNECTED`, `STATE_DISCONNECTING`.

To check if the A2DP device is streaming or not, register for the `BluetoothA2dp.ACTION_PLAYING_STATE_CHANGED` broadcast.

From the documentation of `BluetoothA2dp.ACTION_PLAYING_STATE_CHANGED`:

> This intent will have 3 extras:
>
> `EXTRA_STATE` - The current state of the profile.
>
> `EXTRA_PREVIOUS_STATE` - The previous state of the profile.
>
> `EXTRA_DEVICE` - The remote device.
>
> `EXTRA_STATE` or `EXTRA_PREVIOUS_STATE` can be any of `STATE_PLAYING`,
>   `STATE_NOT_PLAYING`.

Comment: can you invite me to a chat? it is difficult discussing on here